# How to preserve "setsid unity" command

Tags: 16.04, unity, 17.04

After upgrading from version 16.04 to version 17.04 navigation bar, windows, background, dash and generally whole unity stop working. What is helping is "setsid unity" command. But each restart is clearing up this setting. Is there any way to preserve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to terminal, then,

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

then add

```
setsid unity
```

before

```
exit 0
```

and you are done.